# Spring:xml config convert to java config

Tags: java, xml, spring

Im using activiti and spring in project,
XML manner previously configured as follows:

```
<bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
<bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
<bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService" />
<bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService" />
<bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService" />
```

How is configured to convert into JAVA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "repositoryService"
RepositoryService createRepositoryService(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
    return processEngine.getRepositoryService();
}
```

See also documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method