# How to initilize Spring bean using factory method in Java config?

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring in Java based config. I want to initialize a bean using a factory method. In XML, it is done as such:

```
<bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
```

How do I do the same thing in Java?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a similar question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779994/annotation-based-factory-methods)

In your java configuration you have to define the factory bean (processEngine) and call the factory method (getRepositoryService), when defining the repositoryService

Based on the other answer, with your naming it would look like:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
     @Bean
     public ProcessEngine processEngine() {
         return new ProcessEngine();
     }

     @Bean
     public RepositoryService repositoryService() {
         return processEngine().getRepositoryService();
     }
}
```

Comment: i know where this comes from. next to `repositoryService()` there is a call to `identityService(){return processEngine().getIdentityService();}` and a bunch of other "services". How can we avoid the `new ProcessEngine()` to be run multiple times?

Comment: the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116496/springxml-config-convert-to-java-config

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple. You have a factory called processEngine and within factory you have method getRepositoryService, so its should be somewhere like:

```
public class ProcessEngine {
     public XXXX getRepositoryService() {
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: How do I define a Spring bean for this factory method?

Comment: Are you sure it is ProcessEngine and not processEngine?

Comment: The op wants to do it solely with Java code, without xml. He shared the xml code and asked for Java equivalent.